# ios - CATransaction completion called multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

when i use CATransaction completion to wait animation finish, it called the completion many times. which is it should called just once. here is the sample code

```
@objc func spinWheel(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{ [weak self] in
        print("hello")
    }
    startRotation(angle: calculatePosition)
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

so after i swipe an UIView, it will rotate. and after finishing rotate i will try to print. and it will print it about 6-7 times. which should be called just once

Comment: Show the pan gesture code please.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri 
let rotation = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(spinWheel))
rouletteView.addGestureRecognizer(rotation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach for this animation is wrong. When you add a pan gesture to a view and pan it. It keeps calling the delegate as long as you are panning.

So what you should be doing is either replace the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` with `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` or handle the completion when pan gesture ends.

Comment: my mistake, what a silly mistake hahahahahaa, thanks for saving my day :)